# General strategy for litigation against another party who has more financial resources

Tags: litigation, civil

Generally, what is a good strategy when being sue in a civil lawsuit by another party who has more financial resources (e.g., higher income and more assets) or filing civil lawsuits against another party who has more financial resources (e.g., higher income and more assets) because I'm concerned of running out of funds to pay my attorney and the other party can just stall until I'm low on funds and force myself to discontinue or lose my lawsuit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Don't

Don't get into an arse-kicking contest with a mule.

Of course, you don't have a choice if you're the defendant, but if you're the plaintiff, just don't.

### 2. Have insurance

If you are engaged in activities that might reasonably make you the defendant in a lawsuit (like driving a car, running a business, owning a property etc.), take out the appropriate insurance to the appropriate level. Then, defending the litigation becomes your insurer's problem, and resources aren't going to be a problem.

### 3. Negotiate a settlement

Even a bad negotiated settlement will often be cheaper than a successful lawsuit.

### 4. Surrender

Whatever they want, give it to them. Sometimes, the fight is not worth the candle.

### 5. Alternative Dispute Resolution

ADR, like mediation, conciliation, or arbitration, requires the agreement of all parties, but it may be pre-agreed in some contracts. ADR can be cheaper than litigation and is almost always quicker.

### 6. Make settlement offers

Make a generous but realistic settlement offer early. In jurisdictions where costs follow the event, if you get more than the offered amount in the final judgment, you will normally be entitled to actual costs from the date of your settlement offers. Conversely, if you lose but they are awarded less than you offered, you may be entitled to costs from the date you made your offer.

Adjust your offer in light of how well or poorly you are doing.

The corollary of this is always seriously consider any offer you receive.

### 7. Represent yourself

Most of the costs in a lawsuit are lawyer's fees, but the actual court costs are pretty nominal. Depending on your case, you may need to pay expert witnesses, but eliminating lawyer's fees will save you a lot of money.

Of course, this depends on your having the requisite knowledge, ability, and time. In some jurisdictions (e.g., small claims courts), you will have no choice—you have to do it yourself. In others (e.g., the US Supreme Court), the opposite is true—you have to have representation.

### 8. Treat it like a business proposition

Because that's what it is.

What are the risks, and what are the rewards? How likely is each possible outcome? What will it cost to stop right now? What will it cost if I keep going and win, or keep going and lose? Evaluate, reevaluate, and avoid sunk-cost thinking - what you've spent already is gone, and it's not coming back.

### 9. Agree your fees in advance

Don't hand your lawyer a blank cheque.

Most lawyers won't agree to a lump-sum fee, but you don't know unless you ask. Even if they don't, know their hourly rates and place hard limits on how much of your money they can spend without consulting you. Do the same with your experts.

If you or your case are particularly deserving, many law firms will represent you at lower rates or even for free.

### 10. Get more money

Borrow. Accept gifts. Go-fund-me pages.

Comment: "If you or your case are particularly deserving, many law firms will represent you at lower rates or even for free", why would they do that?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld, you donate to charity or volunteer, don't you? So do lawyers

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_bono

Comment: What are the situations where you could demand reimbursement for legal costs if you win?

Comment: @Barmar pretty much everywhere except the USA

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from DaleM](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/101245/9517) is good, but I'd add a eleven more. Mostly they can be summed up by taking a philosophy of not pushing the envelope and focusing on worst case risk/cost-reward scenarios.

### 1. Keep the case simple.

It is frequently the case that you can state a viable legal claim against multiple parties on multiple legal theories in a case. This maximizes the remedies you can receive, hedges against uncertainty about which theory a judge or jury will find most appealing, and maximizes the number of "pockets" that you have to recover from if you win. But suing more parties on more legal theories makes a case more expensive to litigate.

But, when you are suing a defendant with deep pockets, you don't need to have multiple defendants in order to recover everything you could conceivably win in the case.

For example, in another recent Law.SE question, the issue was why someone would only sue the Ford Motor Company for defects causing death for its Ford Pinto, and not also try to sue the engineers involved in its design on a negligence theory. In that case, the Ford Motor Company has deep pockets, so there was no need to name other parties for purposes of making any judgment collectible, and it was easier to prove the case for strict liability product liability against Ford, than to prove other legal theories such as the negligence of the engineers involved or a breach of warranty under the Uniform Commercial Code. Bringing a lawsuit on a single, straightforward, legal theory against a single defendant was less costly than bringing a lawsuit against multiple defendants on multiple legal theories (they could have sued the engineers for negligence and the car dealers that sold the cars for breach of warranty), and the other theories wouldn't have increased the likelihood of collection if they prevailed or the remedies available to winning plaintiffs injured by the defective cars.

### 2. Choose a legal theory which narrows the scope of the relevant evidence.

The legal theories asserted and the parties against whom they are asserted impacts how much evidence is relevant in the case which impacts how expensive it is to litigate.

For example, in a lawsuit for breach of contract where there is a signed written contract in place with a defendant with deep pockets, the existence and validity of the contract and its terms can typically be established on day one with an exhibit to the complaint which will be admitted in the answer to the complaint. Thus, the only issues to litigate will be whether the contract was breached and what damages arose from the breach. In many cases, like a promissory note or a claim for unpaid rent, the existence of a breach of contract and the damages, can be proven entirely with bank and business records, and the testimony in person or by affidavit of a witness that those business records are authentic and complete. The plaintiff owed money for the breach of contract can typically prove the *prima facie* case against the breaching party without any pre-trial discovery whatsoever, although there could be counterclaims and affirmative defenses raised by a defendant that must be identified and rebutted. Still, this single defendant case in which very few specific facts are relevant can be quite affordable to litigate.

### 3. Set up a situation amenable to a simple lawsuit before it gets there.

When you are engaged in interactions with a deep pocketed defendant and have few means of your own, you want your interactions with them to be simple and well-documented.

This might mean setting up the structure of a real estate transaction in a way that contractually narrows what is relevant and makes sure everything is well-documented.

If you are providing a service that puts someone with deep pockets at risk of personal injury, get a waiver of the right to bring most personal injury lawsuits in writing and record the entire interaction with video and sound, so  there is no dispute over how the person's rights are limited and what actually happened. Don't mix and match multiple interactions that could broaden the scope of what is relevant in a later dispute.

### 4. Attempt to secure admissions prior to bringing suit.

Communicate with the potential defendant in writing (e.g. email or text), or in a recorded setting, or with strong, credible third-party witnesses about the events you are suing over before bringing a lawsuit.

Some affluent defendants are savvy and either say nothing or tell a plausible and hard to disprove lie at the outset. But many affluent defendants are full of themselves and less sophisticated than they think that they are, and carelessly admit to wrongdoing in ways that are easily proven if you set up the situation correctly.

For example, suppose you are a college student with few resources who is date raped by a powerful and affluent person. It is frequently possible to get the wrongdoer to admit their wrong doing either in a text message conversation or in a recorded call in a one party recording state as they try to preserve the relationship or their public image.

If the wrongdoer isn't legally savvy, they may not even understand the legal implications of what they are saying if the wording used doesn't sound legalistic. A text message that says "You held me down and had sex with me when I was saying 'no, don't do it,'" might secure a response of "I'm sorry that I overstepped my bounds by doing that," when saying "You raped me," might secure a more defensive response.

### 5. Sue only on claims for which you have clear, unequivocal proof.

Maybe you have absolutely clear proof that the rent wasn't paid on time but only arguably proof that the damages to the premises you rented to the affluent person was more than reasonable wear and tear.

You may want to limit your lawsuit to unpaid rent, even though if all the truth were known, you would also have a claim for damage to the premises in excess of wear and tear, because it makes the case less expensive to litigate.

### 6. Sacrifice maximal damages for a less expensive forum.

Suppose that the affluent person carelessly broke the $30,000 antique vase that was for sale in your store. But the jurisdictional limit of lawsuits in your local county court, which has quick trials and a very limited pre-trial procedure, is $25,000. It may make sense to sue in county court anyway, waiving the possibility of recovering more than $25,000, rather than suing in the local court of general jurisdiction which much more expensive pre-trial procedures and slower trial dates, because reduced litigation costs are more important to you in this situation than getting every dollar of damages that you suffered.

### 7. Sue when you have leverage.

Suppose that you are wronged by a large privately held company that is on the verge of being bought out or going public. If you bring your lawsuit at the critical moment, shortly before any pending lawsuits have to be disclosed and could disproportionately impair the price in or delay their business deal, you can often get a quick settlement if you make a reasonable settlement demand, because they have reasons unrelated to the dispute with you to be free of pending litigation that otherwise would require expensive explanations that would delay a time-sensitive deal.

### 8. Sell some or all of your claim to someone who can afford to bring it properly against a well-funded defendant.

Many legal rights can be sold and assigned to someone else. And, you may not have the resources to bring the lawsuit with your own funds.

You can often, for example, in a personal injury case, but also in other kinds of lawsuits with a clear payday at the end, hire an attorney to take the case on a contingent fee basis. The lawyer gets a third or a half of your recovery, and you get some recovery if the case is won or settled that otherwise wouldn't have been available at all.

Alternatively, sometimes you can sell your legal rights to someone who can afford to prosecute them. For example, you may have a complicated real estate dispute that makes it impossible to use the property for its more profitable purpose, and you don't have the funds to fight that dispute in court. You could sell the property to someone who can afford to fight that dispute in court at a discount that reflects the value that the buyer is adding by being able to afford to litigate in a way that realizes the full value of the property.

If you can't afford to fight that legal dispute, you get none of the value you could have if you won, while in a sale to a third-party, you can get some of that value from a sale prices the reflects the value of winning the dispute but discounts it since the buyer is taking on risk and litigation costs.

### 9. Choose to sue in cases when you have little to disclose and you don't need information.

The biggest cost of litigation is "disclosure and discovery" which is providing information to the other side that you have and obtaining information in the control of the other side from them.

In some lawsuits, you, the Plaintiff, have only so much information to disclose, and you don't need a lot of disclosure and discovery from the other party to prevail in your lawsuit.

For example, if you are suing in an automobile accident where you are rear ended and suffer only economic losses, there may not be many facts that have to be disclosed, and it may be easy to prove that the other party was at fault in the accident without much discovery from them.

These kinds of cases can be affordable to litigate against an affluent defendant.

### 10. Limit your case to well-established legal theories.

After disclosure and discovery, another factor that can drive up the cost of a lawsuit is motion practice over close legal issues.

But this kind of motion practice comes up much more often when you are suing based upon obscure legal theories or legal theories with important unresolved questions.

If you can sue on a well-established legal theory where none of the important issues in the case involve unresolved or complicated legal issues, rather than suing on a novel legal theory that presents issues of first impression or close questions of legal interpretation, you can greatly reduce the cost of litigating your case.

For example, the legal costs in the case of first impression to keep Donald Trump off the ballot on the basis of the 14th Amendment insurrection clause that was litigated all of the way to the U.S. Supreme Court in *Trump v. Anderson* was very expensive for everyone involved in terms of legal fees and involved immense risk for both parties because there were few controlling precedents on this rarely litigated issue.

If you had to choose over suing to keep someone off the ballot because  they weren't old enough or didn't live in the state where they were required by law to live, rather than invoking the insurrection clause, limiting your case to these much more legally settled legal theories would be much less expensive.

### 11. Avoid raising hot button issues.

Sometimes affluent people or organizations will vigorously defend, and refuse to settle a small dollar lawsuit because it has strategic implications or implicates their "honor."

For example, if you have to choose between suing an affluent individual over breaching a contract v. defrauding you, even if you can prove both, you may want to limit your case to the breach of contract claim. A lawsuit for fraud implicates the honor and reputation of the person sued in a way that a breach of contract lawsuit does not. So, the affluent defendant may be willing to spend far more than the case is worth to avoid being found to have engaged in fraud because their reputation is worth far more than the stakes in the lawsuit due to its impact on them in other transactions, than they would over a breach of contract which doesn't implicate their personal reputation in the same way.

Comment: What will be my benefit for "Sell some or all of your claim to someone who can afford to bring it."?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld If you can't afford to sue properly against an affluent defendant, you either sue and lose because you can't afford to litigate properly, or you don't sue and get nothing. If you sell your claim, you get some value for your legal rights.

Comment: But will the other party sue for me?

Comment: If the case is taken on contingent basis the lawyer will sue in exchange for their share. If all of your legal rights are sold, you get your payday at the sale and whether the other person sues is their problem. Not all legal rights can be sold. Sometimes this is "champerty" but some legal rights can be sold.

Comment: Thanks. What are examples of legal rights that can be sold?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld Contract rights, business law claims, property rights claims. But often not personal injury claims and never domestic relations claims